# Sending Memory stream which contains capture image to parse.com on button click

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, parse-platform, memorystream

I am trying to capture a Image and then send that on image to parse.com including other object values. 
To make it short I was sending the image to parse.com as soon as I capture image without even Button_click event. it is working but not what i want. I want to save the memory stream and then use the saved stream to send on parse.com on button click with the other object variables.

This is the code where I am capturing the image and sending it to parse.com

```
  private async void cameraCapture_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK) return;

        var capturedPhoto = new BitmapImage();
        capturedPhoto.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        ImgView.Source = capturedPhoto;

        PictureFileName = today.ToString();
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Get a stream of the captured photo
                var writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(capturedPhoto);
                writableBitmap.SaveJpeg(memoryStream, capturedPhoto.PixelWidth, capturedPhoto.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

                PhotoResult photoResult = e as PhotoResult;

                photoResult.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                memoryStream.Position = 0; // Rewind the stream

                byte[] myPicArray = memoryStream.ToArray();

                ParseFile ImageFile = new ParseFile(PictureFileName, myPicArray);
                await ImageFile.SaveAsync();


                var image = new ParseObject("ImageUpload");
                image["photo"] = ImageFile;
                image["description"] = TextBox.Text;

                await image.SaveAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my button click code where I want to send that image on click instead of sending it directly after capture. i want to save the image stream if possible and then send it to parse.com on button click.

```
private async void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = new ParseObject("ImageUpload");
        image["photo"] = imageFile; //how to bring that memory stream here ???
        image["description"] = TxtBox.Text;

        await image.SaveAsync();
    }
```

Comment: sorry guys! i got the solution.

Comment: You can post your answer also if you find solution so it can be useful for others in future Refrence.

Comment: i actually added the solution in the same question box. i hope you can find it.

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer; you can accept your own. =)

Comment: got it. thnx. answer is added !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void cameraCapture_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {

        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK) return;

        var capturedPhoto = new BitmapImage();
        capturedPhoto.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        ImgView.Source = capturedPhoto;

        FileName = today.ToString();


        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Get a stream of the captured photo
                var writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(capturedPhoto);
                writableBitmap.SaveJpeg(memoryStream, capturedPhoto.PixelWidth, capturedPhoto.PixelHeight, 0, 50);

                PhotoResult photoResult = e as PhotoResult;

                photoResult.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                memoryStream.Position = 0; // Rewind the stream

                myPic = memoryStream.ToArray(); //  byte[] myPic; has been decleared in inital
            }
        }
    }
```

on button click

```
private async void BtnPost_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ParseFile ImageFile = new ParseFile(FileName, myPic);
        await ImageFile.SaveAsync();

        var imageUpload = new ParseObject("ImageUpload ");
        imageUpload["photo"] = ImageFile;

        await imageUpload.SaveAsync();

    }
```